# Edge Save Page As

Tags: windows, windows-10, browser, microsoft-edge

If I visit a page, for example:

https://superuser.com

Sometimes I might want to download the actual page itself. With Firefox, you
can click the menu and select "Save Page As".

Does Edge have a similar option?

Comment: as a workaround, Windows 10 now has cURL, so you can do something like `curl -o index.html https://superuser.com`

Comment: @StevenPenny - Are we talking about (EdgeHTML) or (Chromium) Edge?

Comment: @John - Current version of Chromium Edge absolutely supports saving a page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `Version 81.0.416.72 (Official build) (64-bit)` you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> or click the option in the contextual menu (right-click):

[image]

If it's not working for you, you might need to update it.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are using the latest version of [Microsoft Edge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge), then, yes, you can press Ctrl-S to save the webpage.